# ElasticSearch on EC2 - search queries are blocked

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I have installed ElasticSearch 5.5 on EC2 (not using managed service). the EC2 has elastic ip and all incoming and outgoing rules are open.
I am able to add data and query the mapping, cluster status, templates and so on, however when i try to run a query a data of a certain index, I am getting a timeout. when sending the request within the VPC (using private IP) all is ok. I run tcpdump to see what is going on and for my surprise I didnt see any incoming request when i did a search query, all the other requests were seen in the dump. Then I have installed on a new EC2 elasticsearch cluster, and again the same behavior

what is going on?

Comment: Can you share examples of trying to add data and also trying to run a query?

Comment: Hi li-raz, check on your elasticsearch.yml which interface are you binding to. if its 0.0.0.0 (all interfaces) it should be ok, but if its 127.0.0.1 (localhost) you should not be able to query it from other host than localhost.

Comment: it was firewall that blocked me

Answer (score 0):

it was a firewall issue that blocked the request